# Is $\phi^\dagger \phi (\phi + \phi^\dagger)$ a possible interaction for scalar fields in QFT?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, interactions

In my QFT course, we are looking at writing the most general lorentz invariant, renormalizable lagrangians with hermitian interactions.

However I have never seen the interaction in the title mentioned, where $\phi$ is a complex scalar field. To me it seems this would fulfill all the criteria: in 4 dimensions, it has mass dimension 3, so the theory would be super renormalizable. Is there a reason this is not allowed?

Comment: If $\phi^\dagger \phi (\phi + \phi^\dagger)$ is allowed, you are forfeiting particle conservation (global $U(1)$ symmetry). If so, why don't you consider  $\phi + \phi^\dagger$ as well? If you go over to the dark side, go Darth Vader.

Comment: @MadMax $\phi+\phi^{\dagger}$ can be eliminated via the mass term by a shift $\phi\to \phi+\phi_0$. If you wanna go full Darth Vader you can add $(\phi^{\dagger})^2+\phi^2$

Comment: @yu-v, right, and $(\phi^{\dagger})^3+\phi^3$ to boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is odd under $\phi \to -\phi$ and therefore the energy will be unbounded from below, which is a requirement

Edit following discussion in comments:
We demand that our theories will have an energy spectrum bounded from below. Taking the proposed term to be the only term in the potential energy will violate this, as it is odd under $\phi\to -\phi$. If we combine this with the knowledge that $\langle E \rangle \geq E_{\rm{gs}}$ for any state, where $E_{\rm{gs}}$ is the ground state energy, we see that if this is the highest-power term in our Lagrangian will lead to a configuration that will allow $\langle E \rangle \to -\infty$ (we will just push the VEV of $\phi$ to $\infty$ or $-\infty$).

However, if we have higher-power term with a finite positive coefficient, let's say $(\phi^{\dagger}\phi)^2$, then the energy can be bounded again from below.

One cal also consider such a term in the context of perturbation theory and calculate its effects and contributions, while keeping in mind that the underlying theory could be problematic without a necessary term that will prevent these divergences.

From symmetries point of views, as it was commented, this term violates the $U(1)$ symmetry for a complex field, which is something we would like to keep. But this in itself doesn't make such a term invalid. If you don't mind violating this symmetry, one can add other renormalizable terms (from dimension counting perspective) such as $\phi^2+\rm{h.c.}$.

Comment: unsure this follows--you can have phi3 in 6D

Comment: Interesting, so what is the general statement here? Any scalar field (real or not) should be invariant under $\phi \to -\phi$? Is it easy to give an intuition why oddness in this sense would cause the energy to be unbounded from below?

Comment: Given @alexarvanitakis 's example, it would also be nice to have a source for this statement.

Comment: following @alexarvanitakis comment I would be more hesitant, but I would say that if the Lagrangian has terms which can get a negative expectation value then the ground-state energy would tend to minus infinity (the energy spectrum will be unbounded from below). I can always choose a configuration $\phi$ such that $\langle E \rangle \to -\infty$ which implies unbounded energy. Don't know how it works in 6D

Comment: @alexavarnitakis on the level of perturbation theory only, or is there a constructive QFT model?

Comment: The potential does not need to be even under $\phi \rightarrow -\phi$, but if cannot be unbounded from below, and the fact that this is odd under that transformation implies that it is unbounded. If you added a term $(\phi^{\dagger} \phi)^2$ to your interaction term, the theory is fine, and the potential is neither odd nor even.

Comment: To be clear.. you mean that a *term* may be odd under $\phi \to -\phi$, but the entire *potential* may not be, or else the hamiltonian is unbounded from below. Did I interpret that correctly?

Comment: @doublefelix I suppose my thinking is that if part of your potential rises to $+\infty$, then if the potential is purely odd potential it will be unbounded from below by taking $\phi \rightarrow -\phi$. The more general issue is just that your potential cannot be unbounded from below, and that's easy enough to check for your example (or any example with a scalar field potential).

Comment: Got it, so you are imagining $\phi(x)^3$ as a classical potential (as opposed to operator), and remarking that it is unbounded from below, though this is remedied if a $\phi^4$ term is added. Thank you :)

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov I can't name a corresponding constructive QFT model (but I don't really follow that literature anyway).
To clarify my above comment: phi3 in 6d is power-counting renormalisable (unless I just power-counted wrong) and generally healthy perturbatively to my knowledge. As always one has to check stability etc. carefully. But you generally cannot trust blanket statements like "odd interactions break your theory": for example you can make any theory cubic by introducing enough auxiliary fields.

Comment: @alexarvanitakis boundedness from below of the Hamiltonian isn’t a consistency requirement for perturbative expansions, but it is for a constructive QFT model. It is usually taken to be an extra requirement that we want a perturbative expansion to satisfy in order to be a description of physics.

Comment: @yu-v would you be willing to edit the answer to summarize the results from the discussion? I think it would make a nice contribution for anyone else who finds the question. Or else if you don't mind I might edit it myself.

Comment: @doublefelix done

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov: Yes indeed one has to check stability carefully. I didn't mention that here because it seems tricky even perturbatively. Clearly there's issues at tree level if the OP's term is the only term present, but a $\phi^3$ interaction appears to generate $\phi^4$ terms at e.g. 1-loop which will have a stabilising effect. The only reference I can find that calculates that is one I can't read: https://www.osti.gov/etdeweb/biblio/6551029

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's allowed to me. But this term precludes a straightforward coupling to a $U(1)$ gauge field, and we usually want to do that: under $\phi\to \exp(i\alpha)\phi$, this term is not invariant.

Comment: OP’s question doesn’t mention a gauge field.

Comment: Yes, but QFT courses usually do

Comment: sorry but isn’t that irrelevant (no pun intended)? This is a Q-A website. The question was about the possibility of having such an interaction term, not about coupling it to a gauge field

Comment: I did say it's allowed, right?